# fcntl issues compiling C++

Tags: c++, gcc, fcntl

```
{net04:~/xxxx/wip} gcc -o  write_test write_test.c
In file included from write_test.c:4:
global.h:10: warning: `b' initialized and declared `extern'
```

This code uses fcntl.h and the file-handling functions defined - like open(), write(), close() etc..
The code compiles and works as intended.

```
{net04:~/xxxx/wip} gcc -o  write_test write_test.cpp
In file included from write_test.cpp:4:
global.h:10: warning: `b' initialized and declared `extern'
write_test.cpp: In function `int main()':
write_test.cpp:56: error: `exit' undeclared (first use this function)
write_test.cpp:56: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
write_test.cpp:58: error: `write' undeclared (first use this function)
write_test.cpp:62: error: `close' undeclared (first use this function)
```

When I use it as a CPP source code, why does GCC complain? And curiously, why it doesn't complain for open()? What's even happening here?

Comment: Lots of people use fcntl in cpp code; can you post the #includes for write_test.cpp and the start of global.h (at least up to the warning?)

Comment: These were my includes ...
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include "global.h"

Comment: global.h only had one extern definition - that of char *b="";

Comment: are you using some custom glibc / cross-compiling? the `__gxx_personality_v0` error indicate a corrupted installation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. C++ is more strict about headers - you need: `#include <unistd.h>` to properly get the functions indicated.
2. `global.h` should not be defining b - headers shouldn't initialise variables.
3. When compiling you should use `-Wall -Werror` and that will force you to fix all the dodgy bits of your code.
4. To get `exit()` cleanly you'll need `#include <cstdlib>` (C++) or `#include <stdlib.h>` (C)
5. Use `g++` to link C++ code so that C++ libraries get included. Probably easiest to do the entire C++ compile with `g++`.

Comment: I've corrected my code according to your suggestions and now it does compile fine. But while trying to link it, I'm observing the following errors :

{net04:~/xxxx/wip} gcc -o write_test write_test.cpp
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
__gxx_personality_v0                /usr/tmp/cclwLzgI.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to write_test
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Why's this happening?

Comment: Use g++ to link C++ programs; use gcc to link C programs.  If you mix C and C++, use g++.

Comment: Also, exit() is declared in `<cstdlib>` (C++) or `<stdlib.h>` (C).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler 

Yes, I got that. I 'included'that and compiled it, but had linker issues.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler :

Used g++ and all is fine now, kind of weird why gcc would crib whilst linking.

Comment: I'm sure it *possible* to tell gcc to include all the C++ libraries, but given that g++ is designed precisely to compile C++ (and include appropriate libraries), it seems obtuse to try and use gcc.